# Can I Setup 2 WINS Servers in the Same Subnet?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, subnet, wins

I am looking to setup 2 WINS servers in the same subnet to server as replication partners. We have a legacy device that still relies on WINS. I understand that one WINS server is adequate for a network of 10,000 nodes. I figured two servers are needed so that fault tolerance is included as part of my design. Can this be done successfully? What are the best practices?

Comment: Why are you still using wins?

Answer (score 1):

Having two (or even multiple) WINS servers as replication partners was a fairly standard practice back in the days when WINS servers were more widely and regularly implemented.

The most recent Microsoft documentation that I can find is in reference to Windows 200 Server and Windows Server 2003. That being said, the available documentation should suffice to get it set up and configured.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959260.aspx